# How to access attachments from Contact Object in lightning components for salesforce community user?

Tags: apex, community, lightning-aura-components, community-builder

I have been working on developing salesforce community using community builder with lightning components. I am using rich textbox field on Contact Object to store profile picture which is indeed refering to an attachment on Contact. I need to show this Attachment on profile page for logged in community user.

Here is my SOQL query 
`Select Id, Name, ContentType from Attachment 
                    where parentid=:ContactId  and ContentType in ('image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/gif')` I was using to get an attachment. It's working fine when I executed this on developer console. But it's returning null value when it get executed for community user, hence can't access attachment on lightning page.

**Here is the apex controller method that I was calling to get an attachment for lightning component:**

```
public static List<Attachment> getContactImage(){
User lstUser = [Select Id, contactId, Name, Email, Phone, username, companyname, title, mobilephone from User where Id=:userinfo.getuserId()];
List<Attachment> attachments = new List<Attachment>();

if(lstUser.ContactId !=null)
{
   System.debug('##contactId: '+lstUser.ContactId); 
   attachments = [select Id, Name, ContentType from Attachment 
            where parentid=:lstUser.ContactId  and ContentType in ('image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/gif') order by createddate desc limit 1];
    if(!attachments.isEmpty()){
        return attachments;
    }
}
return null; }
```

**On VF page I was executing same query in constructor of that Apex controller. Below is the code:**

```
public CommunityContactDetailPageController(){

lstUser = [Select Id, contactId, Name, Email, Phone, username, companyname, title, mobilephone from User where Id=:userinfo.getuserId()];
if(lstUser.contactId!=null){
  contactObj =[select id, name, mailingstreet , fax, mailingcity, mailingcountry,mailingcountrycode, mailingstate,mailingstatecode, mailingpostalcode, phone, email, accountId, title, mobilephone  from contact where id=:lstUser.contactId];

 //get contact Image
  System.debug('##contactId: '+lstUser.ContactId); 
  attachments = [select Id, Name, ContentType from Attachment 
        where parentid=:lstUser.ContactId  and ContentType in ('image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/gif') order by createddate desc limit 1];
  System.debug('##Attachments: '+attachments );  } }
```

Comment: I think that the problem here may be the user licence type and not lightning component. Try running this soql query on a VF page controller from this community user, and see if you get the same error...

Comment: I have tried running same soql query on VF page as well and it did't worked for that community user.

Comment: How do you run this query on lightning and how on VF page? please post both codes so we can see exactly what is executing.

Comment: I have posted the code sections used for lightning and for the VF page as well. Please have a look.

Comment: and do you get a good log from the line System.debug('##contactId: '+lstUser.ContactId) on both executes?

Comment: Yes I did get the log for Contact Id on both executes.

Comment: try narrowing down the query to a minimum query: select Id, Name, ContentType from Attachment where parentid=:lstUser.ContactId

Comment: Yeah, I have also tried that but still getting no rows with a query.